# JMenuItem no funciona correctamente en JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, apache-poi, jmenubar

Tengo una ventana creada con un JMenuBar puesto en la parte de arriba. Hasta entonces tenía puesto 2 JMenuItems que funcionaban a modo de botón y abrían otro frame. Hasta ahí todo funciona correctamente. Hoy, me ha surgido la necesidad de meter otro item a ese menú, y siguiendo la lógica de los dos anteriores la he implementado. 
Tras un par de horas mirando por qué puede ser (será la chorrada más grande del mundo) no he conseguido dar en por qué no me sale este tercer item del menú.

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("A\u00F1adir planificado");
        mntmNewMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                AñadirView v=new AñadirView();
                v.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        JMenuItem mntmActualizar = new JMenuItem("Actualizar");
        mntmActualizar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ArrayList<Camion>cm=(ArrayList<Camion>) camiones.getPlanif();
                list.removeAll();
                for(int i=0;i<cm.size();i++) {
                    list.add(cm.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        });
        menuBar.add(mntmActualizar);
        menuBar.add(mntmNewMenuItem);

        JMenuItem mntmVerPlanifSemanal = new JMenuItem("Ver planif semanal");
        menuBar.add(mntmVerPlanifSemanal);
```

Como veis el último item está sin implementar aun, es el que no funciona. Os dejo una captura aquí de mi (primitiva) interfaz para que podáis verlo fácilmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En realidad, al `JMenuBar` cuando le decimos `add` deberíamos pasarle como parámetro un `JMenu`, y a su vez este método `add` nos devuelve también un `JMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo te permite ejecutar la acción sobre cada menuItem y así sucesivamente.

```
public void ventanaMenu(){
    System.out.println("ventana"); // Creando la ventana de alto Nivel contenedor de todos los elementos
    JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
    ventana.setTitle("PRUEBAS");
    Dimension d = new Dimension(500, 500);
    ventana.setSize(d);
    ventana.setPreferredSize(d);


        JMenuBar barra = new JMenuBar(); // Se crea la barra de menu
        JMenu menuPopUp = new JMenu(); // popUp que mostrara los item
        menuPopUp.setText("Archivo");


            JMenuItem menu1 = new JMenuItem("Menu 1"); // MenuItem 1
            menu1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // Agregando el Listener
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { // Ejecutando la accion del click sobre el item
                    System.out.println("Accion menu 1");
                }
            });

            JMenuItem menu2 = new JMenuItem("Menu 2"); // MenuItem 2
            menu2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// Agregando el Listener
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// Ejecutando la accion del click sobre el item
                    System.out.println("Accion menu 2");
                }
            });

            JMenuItem menu3 = new JMenuItem("Menu 3"); // MenuItem 3
            menu3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {// Agregando el Listener
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// Ejecutando la accion del click sobre el item
                    System.out.println("Accion menu 3");
                }
            });


    menuPopUp.add(menu1); // Agregando cada MenuItem al popUp del menu
    menuPopUp.add(menu2);
    menuPopUp.add(menu3);

    barra.add(menuPopUp); // Agregando el popUpMenu a la barra
    barra.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100)); // Estableciendo unas dimensiones para hacerla visible

    ventana.add(barra); // Se Agrega al contenedor de alto nivel JFrame

    ventana.pack();
    ventana.setVisible(true);

}
```